# Is Psalm 118:19 associated with Hallel and Yamim Noraim?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, hallel, high-holidays

Is the verse פתחו לי שערי צדק from [Psalms 118:19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26b8.htm#19) associated with Hallel? When is typically recited and does it have any connection to ימים הנוראים?

Answer (score 1):

Not only is that verse associated with Hallel: it is recited in and as a part of Hallel. Hallel is recited on various red-letter days, not including the ימים הנוראים (but can, as Psalms and not a special Hallel prayer, be recited any day). (Unless you count [*Hoshana Raba*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoshana_Raba) as one of the ימים הנוראים, in which case, yes, Hallel is recited then.)